# ifstream* Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers

I want use type ifstream* open file in my code

```
ifstream* i;
(*i).open("test.txt");
```

It throws a Segmentation fault, I don't know why.
Please help me solve the problem(open file with `ifstream*`) and tell me why it fault.

Comment: You have a pointer, but where does it *point*?

Comment: Also, with modern C++ there are seldom a need to use pointers *at all*.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can't expect to enter some random characters and have it compile as C++. This is cargo cult programming.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `i` is a pointer and it is not initialized, so the memory location it points to is indeterminate.

Next, you are attempting to dereference it in `(*i).....`, which, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory (i.e., make the pointer point to some valid memory location) before you can dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ifstream* i;
```

`i` is a pointer but it does not point to any `ifstream` object. Hence the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Use like that:

```
ifstream i;
i.open("test.txt");
```

Otherwise it fails because your pointer points to nowhere, but not to a valid object.

Or if you still like to use pointers:

```
ifstream* i = new ifstream;
i->open("test.txt");
...
delete i;
```